# Maintain a fixed size heap -python

Tags: python

```
h = []
heapq.heappush(h,(10, 1200))
heapq.heappush(h,(20, 31))
heapq.heappush(h,(5, 1))
```

I want to maintain a fixed heap size of say 3,so when I next have `heapq.heappush(h,(3,15))`,key with value 20 gets deleted and I am left with values 3,5 and 10.Any ideas how?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a max heap or a min heap? If it's a min heap, you're going to have problems, since you need a remove-max operation for this.

Comment: I want a max heap. Then do you if there is any predefined remove min function.

Comment: remove-min is `heapq.heappop`.

Comment: If you want k smallest values, maintain a max heap and get rid of largest elements

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's no built-in in heapq to check the size, so you'll have to do that yourself:

```
if len(h) < capacity:
    heapq.heappush(h, thing)
else:
    # Equivalent to a push, then a pop, but faster
    spilled_value = heapq.heappushpop(h, thing)
    do_whatever_with(spilled_value)
```

Also, note that heapq implements a min heap, not a max heap. You'll need to reverse the order of your priorities, probably by negating them.

Comment: The pop operation in heappushpop returns the smallest item but I need to pop max item when considering min heap.

Comment: @user2991421: Do you need both remove-min and remove-max? If you need both, a heap isn't the tool for the job. If you only need remove-max, reversing the priorities will effectively give you a max heap.

Comment: What I need is given a min heap or max heap remove the max element from min heap or remove the min element from max heap so that when I add a new element I have fixed size heap.

Comment: @user2991421: Yeah, that's not going to work. You need a different data structure, like a binary search tree. Since Python doesn't come with a BST implementation, you'll have to find one somewhere or write your own. Alternatively, you could just keep a sorted list and use `bisect` to find where to insert elements.

Answer (score 9):

I found this post I was trying to implement a top-n heap with fixed size, here is the solution I can offer:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappushpop, nlargest

class MaxHeap():
    def __init__(self, top_n):
        self.h = []
        self.length = top_n
        heapify( self.h)
        
    def add(self, element):
        if len(self.h) < self.length:
            heappush(self.h, element)
        else:
            heappushpop(self.h, element)
            
    def getTop(self):
        return sorted(self.h, reverse=True)
```

and more optimally (thanks to @CyanoKobalamyne)

```
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappushpop, nlargest

class MaxHeap():
    def __init__(self, top_n):
        self.h = []
        self.length = top_n
        heapify( self.h)
        
    def add(self, element):
        if len(self.h) < self.length:
            heappush(self.h, element)
        else:
            heappushpop(self.h, element)
            
    def getTop(self):
        return nlargest(self.length, self.h)
```

Comment: Why use `sorted` rather than `nlargest(self.h, top_n)`?

Comment: According to documentation they are equivalent https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest

Comment: That means that they have the same result, not that they have the same speed. In fact `heapq.nlargest` and `heapq.nsmallest` keep a heap of the n largest (or smallest) elements while iterating through the input, so are signinficantly faster than using `sorted`.

Comment: @CyanoKobalamyne thanks for the explanation. Still the difference is equivalent to `O(log(n))` vs `O(1)` so although it's suboptimal it is not "significantly faster" until you're dealing with very large sizes.

Comment: I think you displaced the arguments of `nlargest` function, the first arg should be the number of items we want to get, the second one should be the iterable.

Comment: @Danialz correct! Will edit, thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want the *k* smallest elements, which is equivalent to discarding the largest element of a fixed-size min-heap on every push, you should use `heapq.nsmallest` (or `heapq.nlargest` for the opposite) on the iterable from which you are building the heap.

Answer (score 4):

Python (as of today v 3.8x) does not have a built in fixed heap size functionality. You have 2 options:

1. maintain a heap and on every push, check if `size > fixedSize` then pop. This means at any given time, the max size of your heap could be `fixedSize+1` which is when you'll pop one.
2. Another option is to use `heapq.heapreplace(heap, item)` which as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapreplace) :

> Pop and return the smallest item from the heap, and also push the new item. The heap size doesn’t change. If the heap is empty, IndexError is raised.
> This one step operation is more efficient than a heappop() followed by heappush() and can be more appropriate when using a **fixed-size heap**.

Comment: Given that `heapreplace` pops first, I think `heapreplace` is best used when the new item must be on the heap (so the smallest item leaves), and `heappushpop` when you'd like to maintain the top-*k* over the history (so the new item may leave).

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this myself, a sorted list of items with a maximum length.

I used a deque due to its 'maxlen' property.

```py
import collections
import bisect

h = collections.deque(maxlen=3)

def insert(h, item):
    if len(h) < h.maxlen or item < h[-1]:
        if len(h) == h.maxlen:
            h.pop()
        bisect.insort_left(h, item)

>>> insert(h, 200); print(h)
deque([200], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 100); print(h)
deque([100, 200], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 200); print(h)
deque([100, 200, 200], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 150); print(h)
deque([100, 150, 200], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 200); print(h)
deque([100, 150, 200], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 1); print(h)
deque([1, 100, 150], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 100); print(h)
deque([1, 100, 100], maxlen=3)

>>> insert(h, 20); print(h)
deque([1, 20, 100], maxlen=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve limited sized heap you could truncate your heap after every push operation.

```
limited_sized_heap = limited_sized_heap[:max_size_of_heap]
```

here is an example.

```
import random
import heapq

max_size_of_heap = 5
limited_sized_heap = []    

for i in range(10):
   a_random = random.randint(1,9)
   heapq.heappush( limited_sized_heap, a_random )
   limited_sized_heap = limited_sized_heap[:max_size_of_heap]
   print(limited_sized_heap)
```

outputs:

```
[3]
[3, 9]
[3, 9, 4]
[3, 4, 4, 9]
[2, 3, 4, 9, 4]
[1, 3, 2, 9, 4]
[1, 3, 1, 9, 4]
[1, 3, 1, 9, 4]
[1, 3, 1, 9, 4]
[1, 3, 1, 9, 4]
```

If you need absolute fixed sized heap instead of limited sized, you can just initial the heap with fixed-sized list with infinite values.

```
fixed_sized_heap = [float('inf')] * heap_size
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in in heapq function to check the size, so you'll have to do that yourself:

```
if len(h) < capacity:
    heapq.heappush(h, thing)
else:
    # pushes the element on and then pops off the top
    heapq.heappushpop(h, thing)
```

Note that heapq implements a min heap, not a max heap. You'll need to reverse the order of your priorities

I see that you specifically mentioned in your post that you would like a max heap with a fixed size of 3, and to be able to maintain the smallest elements when adding a new one in

By negating your elements on insertion into the min heap, you'll be able to use the heappushpop to your advantage. Instead of removing the smallest element and replacing it, you would now be removing the largest element and replacing it

This gives the disadvantage that as you pop elements off, you'll be seeing them in reverse order of size. So you'll have to negate them and reverse their order if you want a correctly ordered ascending list at the end of everything

Here is an illustration:

[A visualization of pushpop when using the default minheap vs when negating the elements of the minheap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaoOa.png)

[Here's an example of how it's implemented in a specific problem with the same requirements outlined in your post](https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/solutions/294389/easy-to-read-python-min-heap-solution-beat-99-python-solutions/)