# python, heapq: difference between heappushpop() and heapreplace()

Tags: python, heap

I couldn't figure out the difference (other than ordinality of push/pop actions) between functions heapq.heappushpop() and heapq.heapreplace() when i tested out the following code.

```
>>> from heapq import *
>>> a=[2,7,4,0,8,12,14,13,10,3,4]
>>> heapify(a)
>>> heappush(a,9)
>>> a
[0, 2, 4, 7, 3, 9, 14, 13, 10, 8, 4, 12]
>>> heappop(a)
0
>>> b=a.copy()
>>> heappushpop(a,6)
2
>>> heapreplace(b,6)
2
>>> a
[3, 4, 4, 7, 6, 9, 14, 13, 10, 8, 12]
>>> b
[3, 4, 4, 7, 6, 9, 14, 13, 10, 8, 12]
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`heapreplace(a, x)` returns the smallest value originally in `a` regardless of the value of `x`, while, as the name suggests, `heappushpop(a, x)` pushes `x` onto `a` *before* popping the smallest value.  Using your data, here's a sequence that shows the difference:

```
>>> from heapq import *
>>> a = [2,7,4,0,8,12,14,13,10,3,4]
>>> heapify(a)
>>> b = a[:]
>>> heappushpop(a, -1)
-1
>>> heapreplace(b, -1)
0
```

Answer (score 15):

in many common cases the ultimate result seems the same, but the process and behavior is different, and can be visible in corner cases:

`heappushpop()` is equivalent to pushing first, then popping, meaning, amongst other things, that your heap size might change in the process (and that, for example, if your heap is empty you'll get back the element you pushed).

`heapreplace()` is equivalent to popping first, then pushing, with the additional restriction of guaranteeing that your heap size won't change in the process. this means you'll get an error on an empty heap, amongst other interesting corner behaviour.

Comment: Can you add what are the other interesting corner behavior?

Answer (score 14):

Very important to know that the reason `heapq` have these methods is to **increase efficiency**
In terms of functionality, you can think like this

```
# if we assume len(list) == k
heapq.heappushpop(list, elem): # 2*log(K) runtime
  heapq.push(list, elem)  # log(K) runtime
  return heapq.pop(list)  # log(k) runtime

heapq.heapreplace(list, elem): # 2*log(K) runtime
  returnValue = heapq.pop(list) # log(K) runtime
  heapq.push(list, elem)        # log(K) runtime
  return returnValue
```

but why having two additional functions when you can do everything with `push`,`pop`?
`heapq.heappushpop()` and `heapq.heapreplace()` **only use log(K) time!**

```
# if we assume len(list) == k
heapq.heappushpop(list, elem):         # log(K) runtime
  if elem < list[0]:
      return elem
  return heapq.heapreplace(list, elem) # log(K) runtime

heapq.heapreplace(list, elem):  # log(K) runtime
  returnValue = list[0]         # peek operation
  list[0] = elem
  heapq.bubbledown(list,0)      # restore heap structure in log(K) time
  return returnValue
```

**the time consuming operation is `heapq.bubbledown`(not actually a python api), under the hood, this function is very similar to [`heapq.pop()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Extract)**

You will notice these functions are very handy when it comes to solve problems like [Merge K sorted arrays](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays/). If you just use `pop` + `push` (like in java), it will be two times slower :(

Comment: Can you explain more why heapq.bubbledown is only log(K) time?

Comment: @spspli because bubble down needs to take at most *h* steps, where *h* is the height of the heap. With every step it goes down one level in that tree. And *h* is *log(K)*.

Comment: Although the chosen answer answers the question, this is much more infromative and useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`heapq.heappushpop` is equivalent to **first push then pop**

while

`heapq.heapreplace` is equivalent to **first pop then push**

as a demo:

```
>>> seq
[0, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3]
>>> heapq.heappushpop(seq, -1)
-1
>>> seq
[0, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3]
>>> heapq.heapreplace(seq, -1)
0
>>> seq
[-1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3]
```

Comment: Just to add to @Syscall comment this link is helpful for new user's: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

My explanation in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443150/maintain-a-fixed-size-heap-python/63922377#comment135737595_63922377) might be useful in addition to other answers from a result-oriented perspective:

- `heappushpop` when you'd like to **maintain the top-*k*** over the history (so the new item may leave). It first compares the top item and the new item.
- `heapreplace` when **the new item must be on the heap** (so the top item leaves). This is done by directly replacing the top item with the new item and re-heapifying.